# In Capture One 20, is there a better way to add titles & captions other than in the IPTC field editor?

Tags: capture-one

In Capture One 20, if I want to add a title and/or caption to a photo, *where* should I write them? I can't seem to find a user interface element in C1 where I can write titles and captions more directly than the ITPC field metadata panel. Editing the IPTC fields is kind of awkward; the list of IPTC fields is long, the input elements are only 1 line high (making it hard to write multiline text), and the most relevant fields are also spread out ("Description" is under *IPTC – Content* while the title is under *IPTC Status*). This seems strange when compared to many other photo applications that support editing title & caption more directly and elegantly.

[image]

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, and that there's another place to write them, and I hope someone here will know a better way.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no other UI to input info there.
Also, keep in mind that what you're inputing is written in C1 database not in the photo itself. You can also choose to use other software (I use Houdah Geo) to input GPS data in the photo, then import it in C1